# Recursive method( Returning the sum of the powers of 2 up to the xth power of 2 as an integer) without using Math.pow

Tags: java, recursion

I'm currently creating a recursive code that does 5 methods and etc. I am having issues with my recursive method, that will return and print in main() the sum of the powers of 2 up to the Xth power of 2. X is a integer on the commandline argument.

I am able to do the math.pow process but how do I do it without using Math.Pow?

My Code (The Issue is the powerCount method).

```
public class TestRun {
/*
* The "main" Method Starts The Program.
* @param args (commandline arguments) are printed to the screen
*/

   public static void main (String[]args) {

   //initialize variables
      int num = 0;
      String result = "";
      /***********************************
    * @ Try-Catch Checks for valid input
      * **********************************/
      try{
         if(args.length == 0)
         {
            System.out.println("ERROR:NO INPUT FOUND.");
         }//end of if
         else
         {
         //convert 1st commandline argument from string to integer    
            num = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
         //method call to 1st method   
            result = rowOfAsterisks(num);
         //display output of 1st method to screen    
            System.out.println(result);
         //method call to 2nd method   
            result = forwardCount(num);
         //display output of 2nd method to screen    
            System.out.println(result);
         //method call to 3rd method   
            result = reverseCount(0, num);
         //display output of 3rd method to screen    
            System.out.println(result);
         //method call to 4th method   
            Integer result2 = addCount(0,num);
         //display output of 4th method to screen    
            System.out.println(result2);
         //method call to 5th method    
            result2 = powerCount(1,(int)Math.pow(2,num));
         //display output of 5th method to screen    
            System.out.println(result2);
         }//end of else
      }//end of try
      catch(NumberFormatException e)
      {
         System.out.print("ERROR: Please input an integer.");
      }
   }//end of main

    /**************************
    * Writes x asterisk
    * @param num is input of the user and will determine the number of asterisks
    * @return x asterisk
    ***************************/
   public static String rowOfAsterisks(int num)
   {
      //base case
      if(num ==1){
         return "*";
      }
      //recursive case
      else{
         return "*" + rowOfAsterisks(num-1); 
      }//end of else
   }//end of method1

    /*****************************
    * Counts from number to zero.
    * @param num is the input of the user or the argument
    * @return string num
    *****************************/
   public static String forwardCount(int num)
   {
      //base case
      if(num==0){
         return num + ", ";
      }
      //recursive case
      else{
         return  num + ", " + forwardCount(num-1);
      }//end of else
   }//end of method 2

    /***************************************************
    * Counts from zero to number.
    * @param initialNum is the input/initial integer
    * @param finalNum is the final integer
    * @return initialNum and finalNum as a String.
    ****************************************************/
   public static String reverseCount(int initialNum, int finalNum)
   {
      //base case
      if(initialNum == finalNum){
         return initialNum + ", ";
      }
      //recursive case
      else{
         return initialNum + ", " + reverseCount(initialNum +1, finalNum);
      }//end of else
   }//end of method 3

    /*****************************************************
    * Adds the number from 0 to number and returns the sum
    * @param initialNum is the input/initial integer
    * @param finalNum is the final integer
    * @return initialNum and finalNum as a String(again)
    ****************************************************/
   public static int addCount(int initialNum, int finalNum)
   {
      //base case
      if(initialNum == finalNum){
         return initialNum;
      }
      //recursive case
      else{
         return initialNum + addCount(initialNum + 1, finalNum);
      }//end of else
   }//end of method4

    /**********************************************************
    * Multiply number by the power of 2 and returns the product
    * @param initialNum is the input/initial integer
    * @param finalNum is the final integer
    * @return initialNum and finalNum as an Integer
    ***********************************************************/
   public static int powerCount(int initialNum, int finalNum)
   {
      //base case
      if(initialNum == finalNum){
         return initialNum;
      }
      //recursive case
      else{
         return initialNum + powerCount(initialNum *2, finalNum);
      }//end of else
   }//end of method5
}//end of class
```

Here is the powerCount method:

```
public static int powerCount(int initialNum, int finalNum)
   {
      //base case
      if(initialNum == finalNum){
         return initialNum;
      }
      //recursive case
      else{
         return initialNum + powerCount(initialNum *2, finalNum);
      }//end of else
   }//end of method5
}//end of class
```

Here is also the method in my main that calls/returns it and prints it

```
// method call to 5th method    
result2 = powerCount(1,(int)Math.pow(2,num));
// display output of 5th method to screen    
System.out.println(result2);
```

Comment: `(The Issue is the powerCount method).` - well just post the relevant code then.

Comment: oops sorry lemme edit

Comment: `Math.pow(x, 2)` is equivalent to `x * x` not `x * 2`

Comment: Is there way not do to math.pow?

Comment: also I highlighted the only method that I need to change on the 2nd code and showed the one that will call the method from the main on the 3rd code

Comment: Hopefully a few tweaks really that is in line with my code.

Comment: @4castle does that mean my code is good? what is throwing me off is the math.pow on my main method that calls it.

Comment: `1 << x` returns the xth power of 2.

Comment: @AndyTurner how would i revise my powercount method though using 1 << x? do i also have the fix my method call (results2) ?

Comment: OH! i guess my issue is not my powercount method but more on my 5th method to call the method on main? which is result2 ?

Comment: This is just bit shift arithmetic.  The sum of powers of 2 up to the nth power is `(1 << (n+1)) - 1`.  Trying to force it into a recursion is a waste of time.

Answer (score 1):

Your biggest problem is too much code, so much so I'm not going to try to debug it.

A recursive impl is as simple as:

```
int pow(int x, int p) {
    return p == 0 ? 1 : x * pow(x, p - 1);
}
```

If you want to print stuff, don't do it in this method. I would do it outside this code in a main loop that iterates p from 1 to n (forget about "efficiency" - this will execute in a few microseconds).

Answer (score 0):

A usable function would have been:

```
/**
 * Calculates n<sup>exp</sup>.
 * @param n the base number.
 * @param exp the exponent.
 * @return the power of n to the exp.
 */
public static int power(int n, int exp) {
    // What is the easiest case (terminating the recursion?
    // - Case exp == 0 return 1
    ...
    // - Case other exp values
    // What do you know about power formulas to reduce exp?
    ... recursion with smaller exp
}
```

Of course `n^exp+1` == `n * n^exp` which reduces exp by 1. But maybe you can find even better reductions.

In your case the block might be the non-math long names, which sometimes fuzzy things. Using `x^n` as names might even be more helpful.

Also the recursion starts with `f(x, y)` and on the next step uses `f(x', y')` that are a kind of reduction. So that for the last step `y'` is a trivial case, and `x'` maybe already the result.

In our case `power(x, n)` will have a last recursive call `power(x_up_n, 1)` or `x_up_n * power(rumpelstielchen, 0)`.